# CSS/Javascript position:fixed image not displaying

Tags: javascript, css, fullscreen

I'm experiencing an issue with full-width divs/imgs.

I'll preface this by saying I know it'd be easy to create one with width:100%, but I'm writing within someone else's code and have to place my content within 8-9 nested divs whose overflow I cannot change from hidden. To get a div/img to appear above/outside these 8-9 divs, I've tried a few strategies, none of which is working, so I'm trying what I consider the bluntest strategy--making the img position:fixed and using offsetTop to calculate the exact position I want the img placed--but when I do this I run into an issue where the img isn't visible and the Chrome developer console thinks it's forever hiding below the window. Code I'm using live + screenshot follows. Fiddle that replicates the issue (make sure to resize the page) [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nsuwfL5n/).

CSS

```
div.full_width {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1); /* default light gray */
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="full_width" id="twilight">

    <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/territory/image/upload/v1461033616/issue-i-utopia/adam-al-sirgany/kuhne_twlight.jpg"/>

</div>
```

JS

```
function fullWidth() {
    var newWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth + "px";
    var newHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight + "px";
    var allImageDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("full_width");
    if (allImageDivs.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < allImageDivs.length; i++) { 
            var image = allImageDivs[i].getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
            var newTop = allImageDivs[i].offsetTop + "px";
            allImageDivs[i].style.height = newHeight;
            allImageDivs[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
            image.style.position = "fixed";
            image.style.left = 0;
            image.style.right = newWidth;
            image.style.top = newTop;
            image.style.width = newWidth;
            image.style.height = newHeight;
            image.style.zIndex = 1000000;
        }
    }
};
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fullWidth);
window.addEventListener("resize", fullWidth);
```

[image at bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl2OV.png)

I'm sure there are better solutions to this problem, which I'm very open to learning, but I'm also curious as to why the img is behaving this way.

Thanks fam.

Comment: where you get the values of `newtop` , `clientWidth` and `clientHeight`?

Comment: get the values in % instead of px. Convert the px to % and use those values in you top and left for image

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do here? Are you saying your code only works when you resize the div?

Comment: @infem newTop is the distance in pixels from the top of the document to the top of the div/img I'm trying to expand. clientWidth/Height are just the document height & width.

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth, the resize comment is just for the fiddle to get the JS to run. What I'm saying is that the code "works" in all cases in that the calculated values for top, left, height, width, etc. are correct, but the img doesn't appear and chrome always thinks it's way below. This behavior doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth, to answer your general question. I just want to make full-width, full-height images from within a bunch of nested divs whose overflow I can't change. The whole position:fixed + JS thing is just my inelegant solution.

Comment: @RehbanKhatri, which values? You're saying I should calculate this--(top of div px - top of document px) / entire document height px--to get the percentage, or is there some cleaner way?

Comment: I mean if you could convert the values  that you have currently in px to percentage, your code should work. Do it for height and width. formula would be (value of px) * width /100

Comment: @RehbanKhatri this didn't work, but the way it didn't work made me realize why the image appeared below the page. The ~23% top value made the image appears constantly at that percentage. I followed up with some other thread and am trying out another solution that uses transform: translateX(), width, and height to force the image to appear full-width but am running into another issue: I can get the transform to work in the chrome developer console, but the exact same code injected into the header isn't working. Ugh.